# Regular expression for Indian mobile phone numbers?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that will match text given the following requirements:

- contains only 10 digits (only numbers)
- starts with 9.

These examples should match:

- 9999999999
- 9876543210

These examples should not match:

- 999999999
- 1234567890
- 8912456789
- qwe3456&ert

It is basically for Indian mobile numbers.

Please provide examples, I have already searched Google and those answers provide over-validation.

Comment: If this question is answered, please mark it as such

Comment: This regex will piss off consumers of DoCoMo and other new operators.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
^9\d{9}$
```

Comment: Then the next task you have, @knowledgehunter, is to click on that big honkin' green tick mark next to this answer.

Comment: update your answer.. (\+91)?(-)?\s*?(91)?\s*?([6-9]{1}\d{2})-?\s*?(\d{3})-?\s*?(\d{4}).. Indian numbers start with either 6,7,8 or 9..

Answer (score 4):

I always prefer the REs that can be used on any engine (so no fancy `"\d"` things):

```
^9[0-9]{9}$
```

or, in a crunch,

```
^9[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$
```

if the RE engine doesn't even have `"{}"`.

Yes, I know the C# engine can do both `"\d"` and `"{}"` but that's not always the case.

Comment: This is very interesting - I wasn't aware of any regular expression implementations that do not support `\d` or `{n}`.

Comment: Some of the "lesser" RE tools (sed/grep/etc) on older UNIXes don't have them. Especially on systems that have different binaries in single-user mode (statically linked so as to have no dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

Try this it is tested

```
^([7-9]{1})([0-9]{9})$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
9{1}\d{9}
```

or without predefined `\d`

```
9{1}[0-9]{9}
```

Comment: Isn't the {1} in 9{1} kind of redundant?

Comment: Also, this matches twenty 9's in a row.  You need anchors.

Comment: I think it would match the first ten and the next ten in separate matches.

Answer (score 1):

^9[0-9]{9}$

Answer (score 1):

Try this it is tested

```
^([9]{1})([0-9]{9})$
```

Answer (score 1):

Chk this out.......
Expression

```
^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$
```

Description : This expression is to validate indian mobile nos

Matches :

> 9836193498
>   +919836193498
>   9745622222

Non-Matches :

> +9197456222222
>   8745622222
>   9836193481

Answer (score 0):

```
^([1-9]{1})([0-9]{9})$
```

Try This 10 digit Mobile No validation = ^([1-9]{1})([0-9]{9})$
This Expression is very useful for Indian Mobile Nos .This Expression doesn't allow first digit Zero(example:0123456789).

Comment: I don't know anything about Indian mobile numbers, but this clearly doesn't meet the condition `starts with 9`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^(((\+?\(91\))|0|((00|\+)?91))-?)?[7-9]\d{9}$
```

Comment: Please use [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) whenever it's appropriate.  Without it, each `\+` in your regex came out as just `+`, which is obviously not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Well,I have written this regular expression to validate Indian mobile number.Basically number in India starts with 7-9 excluding country code( +91 ) and (0).This regex will check mobile number pattern including country code.
for example

- +91-8978989089
- 09090898978
- 9909876767
- 0091-999897678
  are valid number

regex is:

`^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$`

you can check/test your input here [regex validation](https://regex101.com/)