# Regualr expression to validate Indian Mobile numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression for Indian mobile phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151216/regular-expression-for-indian-mobile-phone-numbers)

How to use regular expression for validating the Indian Mobile numbers?

```
Ex:
+919000000098
or 
09000000098
or 
9000000098
or 
+91-9000000098
or 
9908716458
```

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151216/regular-expression-for-indian-mobile-phone-numbers ?

Comment: What have you tried? Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151216/regular-expression-for-indian-mobile-phone-numbers

Answer (score 2):

```
Try that:

^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$
```

Comment: This is not working for 09000000098 case .