# Validate Indian Phone number with optional +91 or 0 preceeding 10 digits

Tags: c#, regex, phone-number

I am using following reg expression to validate Indian phone number. I want optional `+91` or `0` before 10 digits of phone. How can I do it?

```
^[789]\d{9}$
```

Comment: did you try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151216/regular-expression-for-indian-mobile-phone-numbers

Comment: yeah I already checked it. No mention of optional +91 or 0 there.

Comment: ^(0|\+91)?[789]\d{9}$    This did it for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `^([0]|\+91)?\d{10}` as starts with `0` or `+91` and 10 digits after that.

> ..but as you must have seen number starts with 7,8 or 9

Then, you should use `^([0]|\+91)?[789]\d{9}$` which means starts with `7`, `8` or `9` and follows `9` digits after that.

Some random matches;

```
+919802422462
08150166859
```

Comment: @RajuPaladiya But that doesn't have `7`,`8` or `9` after `+91` part as OP stated.

Comment: I tested with this -  ^([0]|\+91)?\d{10}

Comment: Some Telecom operators in India introduced new mobile number series which starts with digit 6.

for that use:  `^([0]|\+91)?[6-9]\d{9}$`

Comment: @SushmitSagar Can you please send a link for that so I can put in the answer?

Comment: @SonerGönül You can find the details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_telephone_numbering_in_India#6xxx_series)

Answer (score 3):

This should do

```
^(0|\+91)?[789]\d{9}$
```

`?` matches preceding character or group optionally..

Comment: \d{10}$,  but as you must have seen number starts with 7,8 or 9.

Comment: ^(0|\+91)?[789]\d{9}$  this should do it, let me check

Answer (score 1):

`(?:(?:\+)91)?[7-9]\d{9}0\` this is the right regex expression with +91 optional

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I disagree: it answers the question

Answer (score 0):

```
^(0|91|\+91)?-?[789]\d{9}$
```

The above regex works for phone number starting with +91-,+91,91,91- or 0.